# Why is the image rendered with decimal pixels?

Tags: html, css, image, render

I'm trying to create a blank page with just the Google logo and I've noticed something very strange: the image isn't rendered in its full size of 272x92, instead it's being reduced.

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm testing this in the latest Chrome browser and here's a screenshot of the render:

[image]

As you can see the image's dimensions are decimals resulting in a blurry render.

Comment: I am using Chrome `49.0.2623.75 beta-m (64-bit)` and the render is `272px X 92px`. No decimal.

Comment: You're zoomed out to 90%.. that's why you have the decimal value..

Comment: Absolutely right, it was the zoom!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.1">
```

I assume it's because `minimum-scale` in the `viewport` meta tag is set to a decimal.

Also, you're zoomed out to 90%.

Press `CTRL + 0` to reset your zoom.